# Using Google docs API for OCR in android

Tags: android, ocr, google-docs-api

I am trying to develop an android app which uses OCR. The app should be able to scan business cards and other documents to pull the content.

Is it possible to implement this using Google Docs Api? 
How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

The [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr) allows to upload PDFs or images and automatically perform OCR to extract their text.

Comment: example ? needed  ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Tesseract](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/&ei=BBuCUfDXK4q3rAfcuoG4CA&usg=AFQjCNHJqIxrcpf5ItbWx8JTRFJOvQIXVA&sig2=NA70vRC7sspFuNO4VTqL-g&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bmk). It's powerful library and it has java wrapper [Tess4j](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/)too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). its free for 1-1000 units/month. you can check [pricing here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will find [OpenCV](https://github.com/billmccord/OpenCV-Android) useful. It's a powerful native library with an Android wrapper.